# Tomcat7 + Maven plugin: Tomcat will not start with my war

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm using `java 8` and `tomcat 7` and `maven 3.3.9` with the maven tomcat plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>8085</port>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

For a while everything worked just fine and `tomcat7:run-war` worked.

And now I'm getting this error for no apparent reason:

```
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run-war (default-cli) @ tomcat-example ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8085/tomcat-example
[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at /Users/shikloshi/java_workspace/webapp-examples/tomcat-example/target/tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: /tomcat-example
Jul 04, 2016 2:30:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8085"]
Jul 04, 2016 2:30:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Jul 04, 2016 2:30:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.693s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jul 04 14:30:45 IDT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/307M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run-war (default-cli) on project tomcat-example: Could not start Tomcat: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: Failed to start component [Realm[MemoryRealm]]: Memory database file /Users/shikloshi/java_workspace/webapp-examples/tomcat-example/target/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml cannot be read -> [Help 1]
```

This is the error:

```
Tomcat: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: Failed to start component [Realm[MemoryRealm]]: Memory database file /Users/shikloshi/java_workspace/webapp-examples/tomcat-example/target/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml cannot be read -> [Help 1]
```

Who is responsible for writing the tomcat configuration inside my target dir and why is it not written?

Comment: on which port did you run configure tomcat in CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml ???

Comment: This is not a port issue, I was using 8086 but this is old logs.
Any way I deleted all the tomcat directory inside the target directory (it is there because I'm using the tomcat maven plugin) and it suddenly worked.

Comment: Please check if there is no old instance of Tomcat process running. This could lock the directory and when you start the plugin it can not write to the file mentioned in error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Execute `mvn clean` in order to clean target dir.

Then try again, the tomcat-maven-plugin would re-create the tomcat folder (including the file `tomcat-users.xml`).

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the target folder from your application and run your app again. It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can try creating a file for tomcat users in:

```
/Users/shikloshi/java_workspace/webapp-examples/tomcat-example/target/tomcat/conf/
```

And then adding this into it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
 <role rolename="tomcat"/>
 <role rolename="admin"/>
 <role rolename="manager"/>
 <user  username="admin" password="admin" roles="tomcat,admin,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: This was not the question asked. -1